# Is it advisable to have a detailed intoduction of yourself on your homepage for the purpose of PASSIVE job search?

Tags: interviewing, resume

I'd like an opinion from those on the hiring side. I'm considering writing a description of myself and publishing it on my personal website. Things like what I do, why I do it, how I approach things, what tasks I prefer, my attitude to the process, organization, quality etc. Nothing arrogant, just a detailed introduction of myself, how I've come to be what I am. Not in place of a CV, but an optional read which will always be there for someone to study, if that someone develops an interest in hiring me. Basically I think it will answer most of the questions (and beyond) that people may try to bring up in a personal interview. I thus will gain some points in the eyes of those looking for exactly my type and also prevent the wrong people (as in with wrong roles for me) from offering me a position I will not like.

UPDATE: I think I may have missed an important moment. Basically I'm in a passive job search. I don't currently send out resumes or apply to positions. I thought of putting my introduction there for those who develop a specific concrete interest in me through knowing what I do. It's not a question of putting something in a cover letter or omitting it. Besides, the introduction is going to be lengthy, far longer that could be deemed reasonable for typical application documents. So this is going to be an entirely optional read which I expect to be looked into only by those who already sort of interested in me.

Comment: A bigger question would be: Do hiring managers look at anything other than a CV when determining whether to interview a candidate?  I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: I'm more interested in this having an effect in a passive job search when people already have arrived on my homepage.

Comment: In my experience, there's no such thing as a passive job search. Just like owning a business you have to market yourself actively and not just hang a shingle out and hope people will come along.

Comment: i'd suggest you save yourself the bother and just sign up to linkedin, unless you're going for one of those "viral" job hunting cv websites, like these people: http://www.businessinsider.com/11-creative-resumes-that-have-gone-viral-2013-2?op=1

Comment: I don't want to use LinkedIn - there's no way to prevent my personal information be seen by those I don't want to see it. Besides, you can't delete a LinkedIn account.

Comment: "there's no way to prevent my personal information be seen by those I don't want to see" - This is a problem on all public web pages.
How do you see potent employers stumbling onto your web page?

Answer (score 2):

If you're already a blogger and you have a history of relevant, updated content and actual readership, it won't hurt to have an entry about yourself and details about your working style, skills and aspirations.

On the other hand, if the website is just a one-off vanity site, I don't think you'll get much out of that. No one wants to read a long article about a stranger without much context.

The best way for professionals to put themselves out there for the purpose of a passive job search is through a well-maintained LinkedIn profile. These are actually searched by potential employers and headhunters. Your contacts are also vitally important as these connections are a way for people to share second or third contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd put such relevant info in a cover letter.

A website is better for additional stuff such as personal projects which may indeed demonstrate other qualities you possess, but which is entirely optional and that potential employers can skip if they're not interested.

On the other hand, use a cover letter to supplement your CV with concrete reasons why you are a good fit for the job.

Comment: What I have in mind is probably going to be too long to be put in a cover letter. So the only place where it would fit is a page on my website.

Comment: If it's too big to put in a cover letter, odds are against anyone reading it all. Don't tell. Show.

Comment: @keshlam couldn't have said it better. Recruiters often don't even read CVs, because they're longer than a two-pager. You need to convey your message as concisely as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your expectations are for a passive job search, so you may want to decide what you want to get out of it. Then you can decide on the content. Like many things on the internet, it takes some work to direct people to any site. If you plan on getting a great job in the near future this way, You'll need more self-promotion. You could create a LinkedIn profile or even a Facebook page if you want.

Other than showing your ability to build a website and possibly demonstrate online marketing capabilities, I'd hate to think anyone would hire you or choose not to hire you based on the content. "Can't hire this person. They like to sky dive which is very dangerous. What would be do if there was an accident?" The imaginations are going to run wild.

You would be better off doing some sort of job related blog. Written communication skills, technical know-how, and the willingness to take the time to put it out there will impress more people IMHO.